# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null?

Tags: javascript, html, two.js

Error

```
two.js:3390 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
at root.Two.appendTo (two.js:3390)
at test2.html:14
```

The error happens in this line in two.js

```
elem.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
```

this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="./two.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<script>
var elem = document.getElementById('draw-shapes');
var params = { width: 285, height: 200 };
var two = new Two(params).appendTo(elem);

var circle = two.makeCircle(72, 100, 50);

circle.fill = '#FF8000';
circle.stroke = 'orangered'; 
circle.linewidth = 5;

two.update();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I just started learning Javascript. how to solve this???

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any element in your HTML with the id "draw-shapes".

Comment: The problem is that `elem` is undefined, presumably because there's no element with id `draw-shapes` when you call `document.getElementById('draw-shapes')`.

Comment: @L.Vadim no that's not necessary; "two.js" is a publicly available library and is probably not at fault here.

Comment: What is renderer?

Answer (score 0):

Your `elem` variable is `null` because there is no element with the id `draw-shapes`. The only element in the html body is your script tag.

You could either make a `div` in the html body:

```
<body>
    <div id="draw-shapes"></div>
    <script> ... </script>
</body>
```

Or add the Two instance to the body like this:

```
var elem = document.body;
...
var two = new Two(params).appendTo(elem);
```